# Remove body tag within iframe with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, iframe, same-origin-policy

I'd like to remove an unnecessary header from an iframe contained within the prettyPhoto lightbox plugin that's part of WooCommerce (http://www.shapur.com/product-category/fp-journe/). When you click on the single product button at the bottom of that page, it should remove the body tag contained in the iframe. The iframe conforms to the same origin policy, so that's not it.

I've created a test page here on same domain, which works great: http://www.shapur.com/test.php.

Is there a conflict with the lightbox? I just don't understand. Grateful for any assistance.

Here's the code for the test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe id="myframe" src="http://shapur.com/index.php"></iframe>

<p>Click the button to change the style of the body tag contained in the iframe.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myframe");
        var y = x.contentDocument;
        y.body.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The Iframe content would not be visible inside the DOM of the page which has the iframe, so you cant change it.In order to remove it, you would need to trigger event on the page which is hosted through the iframe.

Comment: need to make sure the iframe is loaded first

Comment: @DinoMyte On the test page (http://www.shapur.com/test.php) I was able to trigger the event on the page hosted in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's coming from the same origin, why don't you use jQuery `load()` function:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
       $(".myDiv").load("/index.php",function(data){
          $(data).find('body').css("display","none");
       });
    }
</script>
```

And have an empty :

```
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

This way, it would be easier for you to play around with the code.

Comment: Sounds like a great suggestion. Ajax is part of Wordpress core, any idea how I would implement this in my test page above. I tried using your code above but it's not working.

Comment: Oops I meant to say **jQuery** `load()` function mate! My bad! And [Ajax is a functionality of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). You can include the google's jQuery library at the top of your code if it doesn't work (see the code edited). Let me know if you are getting any other errors.